# How are signalling pathways specific when secondary messengers are not?

Tags: biochemistry, physiology

I'm a biochemistry and physiology student and am aware that secondary messengers like cAMP and IP3 are used in specific signaling cascades.
However, they and other molecules can innervate a variety of effector molecules which makes me wonder how specificity is maintained.

For example, if GPCRa/Gsa activation leads to the activation of PkAa, why doesn't it lead to the activation of PkAb?